# add picturebox in windowsform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I tried to add picturebox in windowsform on load event-handler but the images didn't appear in the form after loading 
`attachimage` is a picturebox I added it from toolbox ( not by c# )

```
private void ViewCmap_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ConceptProperties.ConceptsMap.Count; i++)
            {
                conceptattchboxlist.Add(new PictureBox());
                conceptattchboxlist[i].Visible = true;
                if (ConceptProperties.ConceptsMap[i].Attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    PictureBox new_attach_box = new PictureBox();
                    new_attach_box.Image = attachimage.Image;
                    new_attach_box.Width = attachimage.Width;
                    new_attach_box.Height = attachimage.Height;
                    new_attach_box.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                    new_attach_box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    new_attach_box.Location = new Point(ConceptProperties.ConceptsMap[i].Coords[0] + (ConceptProperties.ConceptsMap[i].Coords[2]), ConceptProperties.ConceptsMap[i].Coords[1] + (ConceptProperties.ConceptsMap[i].Coords[3]));
                    conceptattchboxlist[i] = new_attach_box;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < ConceptProperties.ConnectionMap.Count; i++)
            {
                connectionattchboxlist.Add(new PictureBox());
                connectionattchboxlist[i].Visible = true;
                if (ConceptProperties.ConnectionMap[i].Attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    PictureBox new_attach_box = new PictureBox();
                    new_attach_box.Image = attachimage.Image;
                    new_attach_box.Width = attachimage.Width;
                    new_attach_box.Height = attachimage.Height;
                    new_attach_box.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                    new_attach_box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    new_attach_box.Location = new Point(ConceptProperties.ConceptsMap[i].Coords[0] + (ConceptProperties.ConceptsMap[i].Coords[2]), ConceptProperties.ConceptsMap[i].Coords[1] + (ConceptProperties.ConceptsMap[i].Coords[3]));
                    new_attach_box.Show();
                    connectionattchboxlist[i] = new_attach_box;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `this.Controls.Add(new_attach_box)` to add a new PictureBox to the form. But why are you doing two identical loops like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a pictureBox or any control use:

```
PictureBox pic = new Picturebox();
this.Controls.Add(pic);
```